# Mocking a HttpClient with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, mocking, jestjs

I'm having trouble with my React Native + Jest + Typescript setup.

I'm trying to test a thunk/network operation. I've created a networkClient function:

```
export const networkClient = async (
  apiPath: string,
  method = RequestType.GET,
  body = {},
  authenticate = true,
  appState: IAppState,
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>
) => {
    ... validate/renew token, validate request and stuff...

    const queryParams = {
      method,
      headers: authenticate
        ? helpers.getHeadersWithAuth(tokenToUse)
        : helpers.getBaseHeaders(),
      body: method === RequestType.POST ? body : undefined,
    };
    const fullUri = baseURL + apiPath;

    const result = await fetch(fullUri, queryParams);
    if (result.ok) {
      const json = await result.json();
      console.log(`Result ${result.status} for request to ${fullUri}`);
      return json;
    } else {
      ... handle error codes
    }
  } catch (error) {
    handleNetworkError(error, apiPath);
  }
};
```

Now, when writing my tests for the operations which uses the networkClient above to request server data like so:

```
  const uri = `/subscriptions/media` + tokenParam;
  const json = await networkClient(
    uri,
    RequestType.GET,
    undefined,
    true,
    getState(),
    dispatch
  );
```

I'd like to mock the implementation to return a mock response pr. test.

As pr the docs, I thought this could be done like so:

```
import { RequestType, networkClient} from './path/to/NetworkClient';
```

and in the test:

```
networkClient = jest.fn(
  (
    apiPath: string,
    method = RequestType.GET,
    body = {},
    authenticate = true,
    appState: IAppState,
    dispatch: Dispatch<any>
  ) => {
    return 'my test json';
  }
);

const store = mockStore(initialState);
return store
      .dispatch(operations.default.getMoreFeedData(false))
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        expect(store.getState().feedData).toEqual(testFeed);
        // fetchMock.restore();
      });
```

but networkClient is not defined, and ts tells me

```
[ts] Cannot assign to 'networkClient' because it is not a variable.
```

---

What did I get wrong? I must have missed something about how Jest mocks modules and how to provide a mock implementation somewhere, but I can't find it on neither the docs, nor on Google/SO.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `automock=false` , btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution

The import should not be

```
import { RequestType, networkClient} from './path/to/NetworkClient';
```

but instead the module should be required like so:

```
const network = require('./../../../../networking/NetworkClient');
```

After that, i could successfully mock the implementation and complete the test:

```
const testFeed = { items: feed, token: 'nextpage' };
network.networkClient = jest.fn(() => {
  return testFeed;
});
```

I hope it helps someone